# Dropzone display images and reqeue them to upload again with new file if any

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am trying to upload the images which works fine.
I got displayed the files in dropzone from folder it works. But when i click on submit button it does not work or submit the form.

**I tried to put a condition to check if there are queued files. The pre-loaded files are not getting queued. So, on submit it does not get any file it shows ( 0 ).**

```
var count = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length;
if (count == 0) { alert(0); }
```

I want to re-queue those files as well as while displaying in the dropzone.
So, if submit button is clicked those files should re-upload/replace the files on server/folder.

**UPDATE**

> now it is showing this error (TypeError: FormData.append: Argument 2 does
> not implement interface Blob.)

**Form HTML**

```
<form name="foo" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="edititemmainsingleallsubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">
<div class="m-portlet__body">
    <div class="dz-message">
        <div class="dropIcon">
            <i style="font-size: 100px;" class="fa fa-upload"></i>
        </div>
        <h3>Drop files here.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="dropzone-previews">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Dropzone.options.myDropzone**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropzone-previews').sortable();
});

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
autoProcessQueue: false,
uploadMultiple: true,
parallelUploads: 5,
maxFiles: 5,
init: function() {
var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");
var myDropzone = this; // closure
var item_id = 1;

$.ajax({
    url: 'item_images.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {request: 2, item_id: item_id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        $.each(response, function(key,value) {
            var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };
            myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
            myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, value.path);
            //myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
            myDropzone.emit("QUEUED", mockFile);
            myDropzone.files.push(mockFile); // added this line
            myDropzone.options.maxFiles = (myDropzone.options.maxFiles - 1);
        });
    }
});

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var files = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles();
    files.sort(function(a, b){
        return ($(a.previewElement).index() > $(b.previewElement).index()) ? 1 : -1;
    });
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
    myDropzone.handleFiles(files);
    myDropzone.processQueue();
});

this.on('completemultiple', function(file, json) {
    $('.dropzone-previews').sortable('enable');
});

this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    $("#submit").show();
});

myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
    formData.append('token','null');
});

myDropzone.on('success', function(file, resp){
    console.log("success");
    window.location.href = "all/items/single/";
});

}
};
</script>
```

**item_images.php**

```
<?php
$itemid = $_POST['item_id'];
$target_dir = "../inc/items/images/items/".$itemid."/";

$request = 1;
if(isset($_POST['request'])){
    $request = $_POST['request'];
}

if($request == 2){
    $file_list = array();
    $dir = $target_dir;
    if (is_dir($dir)){
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
                    $file_path = $target_dir.$file;
                    if(!is_dir($file_path)){
                        $size = filesize($file_path);
                        $file_list[] = array('name'=>$file,'size'=>$size,'path'=>$file_path);
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($file_list);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Pls add your *minimal* HTML - just the form or whatever HTML elements are involved.

Comment: @Don'tPanic please check added the form HTML

Comment: @Don'tPanic any hope?

Comment: I actually spent qiute a bit of time on this the other day but so far without success.  Will try again. There is a lot of contradictory and confusing info about this, it is surprisingly obtuse.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i checked this part is making issues from **dropzone.js**       `for (var i = 0; i < dataBlocks.length; i++) { var dataBlock = dataBlocks[i];
        formData.append(dataBlock.name, dataBlock.data, dataBlock.filename);
      }` when i remove this part it shows success sign but doesnot upload the file in the folder

Comment: So you have been able to submit an image from your webpage to your server to save? Like you've made a very basic form to try and upload an image to save, and everything was configured correctly and it worked?

Comment: @ShanerM13 no it is showing the existing files on edit page and after removing this code and adding a new image it is showing success sign after submit but it is not saving the new image in the folder whatever was added.

Comment: So I am suggesting that you create a very simple page to submit files first. It would make sure that your end to end is properly configured. I don't know if you add these dynamically, but if you want to submit things from an html form, you need to make sure they have <input> tags. The only other way around submitting data is through ajax, where you wont need a <form> tag. Maybe it submits to the same url, but needless to say, it'd be a basic page to just make sure your end to end is configured correctly.

Comment: @ShanerM13 same error

Comment: Is there a console error or do you mean same error as in its not submitting? If there is an error in the console, would you comment it here?

Comment: In your simple html form, make sure to include a `<input name="item_id" type="file">` otherwise when you submit it to the server, your `$itemid = $_POST['item_id'];` will be null, and of course a `<button>Submit</button>` inside of your form to submit it.

Comment: @Shmack it would be great if you can make an working example as a answer?

Comment: @Shmack `Uncaught TypeError: FormData.append: Argument 2 does not implement interface Blob.
    _uploadData http://localhost/site/admin_s/js/dropzone.js:2096
    uploadFiles http://localhost/site/admin_s/js/dropzone.js:1990
    _loop http://localhost/site/admin_s/js/dropzone.js:2112
    transformFile http://localhost/site/admin_s/js/dropzone.js:574
    _loop http://localhost/site/admin_s/js/dropzone.js:2109
    _transformFiles http://localhost/site/admin_s/js/dropzone.js:2117
    uploadFiles http://localhost/site/admin_s/js/dropzone.js:1917`

Comment: `processFiles http://localhost/backyardlane/admin_s/js/dropzone.js:1833
    processQueue http://localhost/backyardlane/admin_s/js/dropzone.js:1794`